# Why am I getting a NaN error using an "else if" statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm an absolute beginner, so I apologize in advance for the noob questions, but here it goes. I don't understand why I'm getting a `NaN` error with this code from the online course I'm taking:

I can do it using a `switch` but I want to understand why I'm getting an error using the `else if`.

```js
const getSleepHours = day => {
  if (day === 'Monday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'Tuesday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'Wednesday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'Thursday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'Friday') {
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'Saturday') {
    return 8;
  }
}


const getActualSleepHours = () => getSleepHours('Monday') + getSleepHours('Tuesday') + getSleepHours('Wednesday') + getSleepHours('Thursday') + getSleepHours('Friday') + getSleepHours('Saturday') + getSleepHours('Sunday');

console.log(getSleepHours('Tuesday'));
console.log(getActualSleepHours());
```

Comment: You forgot "Sunday"

Comment: Because giving `"Sunday"` returns `undefined`?

Comment: Also, `NaN` is not an error, it's just another possible value.

Comment: If voting this question down, please include constructive criticism in the comments.

Comment: @mrpotocnik Hovering over the downvote arrow already gives an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, @Ivar. I was actually unaware of that feature. Good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Federico klez Culloca mentioned, asking for `'Sunday'` is returning `undefined`, because there is no condition for it.

> Calculating with `undefined` will always return `NaN` becuase `undefined` is **Not a Number**

---

Your solution could be adding a condition for 'Sunday' or adding an `else`-statement.

> I think you should add both of them to make sure that your function will not break again if your string is wrong. Take a look at the example below:

```js
const getSleepHours = day =>{
  if(day === 'Monday') return 8;
  else if(day === 'Tuesday') return 8;
  else if(day === 'Wednesday') return 8;
  else if(day === 'Thursday') return 8;
  else if(day === 'Friday') return 8;
  else if(day === 'Saturday') return 8;
  else if(day === 'Sunday') return 8;
  else return 0;
}


const getActualSleepHours = () => getSleepHours('Monday') + getSleepHours('Tuesday') + getSleepHours('Wednesday') + getSleepHours('Thursday') + getSleepHours('Friday') + getSleepHours('Saturday') + getSleepHours('Sunday');

console.log ('Tuesday:', getSleepHours('Tuesday'));
console.log ('getActualSleepHours:', getActualSleepHours());

console.log ('Sundax instead of Sunday: ', getSleepHours('Sundax'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a condition for Sunday will take care of the issue.

```
else if(day === 'Sunday') { return 8;}
```

here is where it breaks: `+ getSleepHours('Sunday');`

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a if condition for `Sunday`.

```
const getSleepHours = day =>{
  if(day === 'Monday'){
    return 8; 
  } 
  else if(day === 'Tuesday'){
    return 8; 
  }
  else if(day === 'Wednesday'){
    return 8; 
  }
  else if(day === 'Thursday'){
    return 8; 
  }
  else if(day === 'Friday'){
    return 8; 
  }
  else if(day === 'Saturday'){
    return 8; 
  } else if (day === 'Sunday') {
    return 8;
  }

}


const getActualSleepHours = () => getSleepHours('Monday') + getSleepHours('Tuesday') + getSleepHours('Wednesday') + getSleepHours('Thursday') + getSleepHours('Friday') + getSleepHours('Saturday') + getSleepHours('Sunday');

console.log (getSleepHours('Tuesday'));
console.log (getActualSleepHours());
```

Comment: Or an `else`, if you don't want to explicitly have "Sunday"

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca although in that case `getSleepHours("January")` will also return `8`.

Comment: he should add the condition for Sunday and also an else which will return 0.